# Matlab subplot function not working

Tags: matlab, plot, subplot

I have been trying to use the subplot function in Matlab, using the following code:

```
x = 0:10;
figure
subplot(2,2,1); plot(x,data_matrix(1,:))
subplot(2,2,2); plot(x,data_matrix(2,:))
subplot(2,2,3); plot(x,data_matrix(3,:))
subplot(2,2,4); plot(x,data_matrix(4,:))
```

However, when I run this simple code, the only thing that displays is a single figure with a plot of the last data vector, `data_matrix(4,:)`. No errors show up. Rather, subplots are simply not being generated. Am I doing something incorrectly, or is there a potential error with my programming environment that's keeping me from displaying subplots?

Comment: clear everything, and comment out 'figure'. Does that help?

Comment: No, I still get the same result.

Comment: Transpose matrices likes `data_matrix(1,:).'`.

Comment: I just tried that, and it also doesn't work.

Comment: Restart matlab?

Comment: And does each one plot individually? Remove subplot, and just plot each one. That way you can make sure there isn't something going on in your matrices.

Comment: No, only the final data array plots. I have tried plotting all of them separately, and they plot just fine. I'll try restarting Matlab now.

Comment: I restarted Matlab, and I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: Does it work if you use `plot(x, x)` instead of `plot(x,data_matrix(1,:))`? If so, please update your example to this simplified case. See [mcve]. It is always a good idea to make a complete example, i.e. define all input variables (f.e. with random data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `data_matrix(1,:)` contains what you expect? You might want to check that out. Also, it'd great if you provided the minimal piece of code that reproduce your problem. Provided piece doesn't reproduce the problem because you don't provide access to `data_matrix` matrix which I suspect is causing the problem, because running this piece of code

```
x=0:10;
data_matrix=rand(4,11);

figure
subplot(2,2,1); plot(x,data_matrix(1,:))
subplot(2,2,2); plot(x,data_matrix(2,:))
subplot(2,2,3); plot(x,data_matrix(3,:))
subplot(2,2,4); plot(x,data_matrix(4,:))
```

works perfectly, as you can see below (I used a rand to recreate a well-formed `data_matrix` matrix)

[image: output of piece of code]

Comment: `data_matrix` is simply a 4 x 11 matrix containing decimals. I have already checked the data to make sure there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: When I run the code you provided, using a randomly created `data_matrix`, I still have the same issue. Only one plot is displayed.

Comment: Which version of matlab are you using? Run `ver` on matlab's prompt

Comment: I am running the following version of Matlab: `8.5.0.197613 (R2015a)`.

Comment: Hmm, that is a modern version so there should not be any problems. Instead of `subplot(m,n,p)` try `subplot mnp` and run again your code.

Comment: This is more a workaround than a solution, it should work the way you wrote it. The solution I provided is a legacy command available only for backwards compatibility.